# Spring Boot ActiveMQ MessageConversionException and Serialization Issue

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I worked on 2 module one with Java EE named "KafkaRest" and another in Spring Boot name "Segmenter". I'm facing challenges while attempting to consume messages from an ActiveMQ queue in my Spring Boot consumer project. Initially, I encountered a `MessageConversionException` indicating that the `_type` property could not be found on the message. After adding `_type` to the KafkaRest producer, I faced a new error related to deserialization.

Here's a snippet of the modified `sendToSegmenter` method in the KafkaRest producer:

```java
public void sendToSegmenter(PrepareStreamVo prepareStreamVo) throws JMSException {
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = JsonUtil.getJson(prepareStreamVo);
        BytesMessage bytesMessage = getSession().createBytesMessage();
        bytesMessage.writeBytes(json.getBytes());
        try {
            getProducer().send(bytesMessage);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.error("fail send message to segmenter with producer message={} error={} ", json, e.getMessage());
            getFallBackProducer().send(bytesMessage);
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("fail send message to segmenter with FallBackProducer message={} error={} ", json, e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
```

Errors Encountered:

```
org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not find type id property [_type] on message 
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException:
Listener method ... threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException:
Failed to resolve type id 
[org.sc.oauth2.resource.server.model.PlaceForm]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.sc.oauth2.resource.server.model.PlaceForm Second Error After Modification: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token active mq Cannot convert from [[B] to [org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage] for String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object**
```

What was causing the initial `MessageConversionException` and `ClassNotFoundException` errors related to the `_type` property, and why did adding it not resolve the issue?

After modifying the KafkaRest producer to use `TextMessage` the errors were resolved. Why did this change fix the deserialization issues?

Are there any recommended best practices for handling message conversion and serialization/deserialization with Spring Boot and ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause of Initial Error:**
The initial MessageConversionException and ClassNotFoundException errors usually point to issues with message conversion and type information during deserialization. The error specifically indicates that the type id property "_type" could not be found on the received message. Adding "_type" is generally a good practice to aid in proper deserialization on the consumer side.

However, the addition of "_type" might not have been sufficient due to the serialization format being used or other underlying issues.

Modification to TextMessage:
The modification made to use TextMessage in the KafkaRest producer is a crucial insight. The choice between TextMessage and BytesMessage affects how the message is serialized and deserialized.

TextMessage is suitable for sending text-based messages. When using this format, the message content is expected to be a text representation, and it avoids the need for additional type information properties like "_type".

**Recommendations:**

1. Ensure Proper Type Information:

   When using the "_type" property, ensure that it correctly reflects the class type of the serialized object. The consumer relies on this information for proper deserialization.
2. Serialization Format:

   When working with JMS and ActiveMQ, it's essential to ensure that the serialization format is consistent between the producer and consumer. In this case, the switch to TextMessage suggests that a text-based format is more appropriate for your use case.
3. Debugging:

   Use logging and debugging tools to inspect the message format being sent and received. This can help identify any discrepancies and provide insights into the serialization and deserialization processes.

By addressing these recommendations, you can ensure smoother message conversion and avoid deserialization issues. The choice of serialization format, especially when dealing with text-based messages, plays a crucial role in the successful exchange of data between the producer and consumer.
The problem solved easily just by change the type of Consumer from Byte to Text:

```
public void sendToSegmenter(PrepareStreamVo prepareStreamVo) throws JMSException {
    String json = null;
    try {
        json = JsonUtil.getJson(prepareStreamVo);
        logger.info("prePareStreamVo in sendToSegmenter: {}",prepareStreamVo.toString());
        TextMessage bytesMessage = getSession().createTextMessage();
        bytesMessage.setText(json);
        try {
            getProducer().send(bytesMessage);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.error("fail send message to segmenter with producer message={} error={} ", json, e.getMessage());
            getFallBackProducer().send(bytesMessage);
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        logger.error("fail send message to segmenter with FallBackProducer message={} error={} ", json, e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```